Trouble setting Field Dependencies for custom scripts in ManageEngine ServiceDeskPlus
I am currently trying to create a script in ServiceDeskPlus that creates a three-field dependency between division, district, and subdistrict as shown below,
Example of image
whereby if the user selects a division, it would showcase the various districts in said area, and after selecting the district, it would showcase the various subdistricts in that area (if any).
The issue is that I am currently getting the error:
"ReferenceError: $CS is not defined at eval"
And I am unsure on what the issue is on my script.
Guide 1
Guide 2
I have followed the scripts based on the guides given by ManageEngine as shown in the hyperlinks above. During the first few tries when it did not work, I created a test template and tried to replicate the contents of Guide 2, with the sample code also being written in Guide 1 ($CS.setFieldDependency(dependencyObject)). I am unsure if I missed a step, but I was met with the same error as mentioned earlier whereby:
"ReferenceError: $CS is not defined at eval"
Here's an example snippet below, it is using Javascript, and "$CS" is proprietary to ServiceDeskPlus

    var dependencyObj = {
      "FIELDS": [
        "Division",
        "District",
        "Sub-District"
      ],
      "VALUES": {
        "Kuching": {
          "Kuching": ["Padawan"],
          "Bau": [],
          "Lundu": ["Sematan"]
        },
        "Samarahan": {
          "Samarahan": [],
          "Asajaya": [],
          "Simunjan": [],
          "Sebuyau": [],
          "Gedong": []
        }
      }
    };
$CS.setFieldDependency(dependencyObj);

I hope to get a solution to this issue.
